# Send parameters that are being set in a javascript from one jsp to another jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

Im quite new to JSP and javascript. Im calculating distance between two places using javascript and storing the distance in a textbox. `document.getElementById('dist').value = drivingDistanceKilometers;`

However when i try to retrieve the value using `String dist = request.getParameter("dist");` I get no value.

Also i tried using `document.location.href = "bookings.jsp?dist="+drivingDistanceKilometers;`
This works for the first time but when I try again it gives no value.

How do I solve this problem?

Sharing more code:

This is inside book.jsp

Javascript:

```
<script>
var geocoder, location1, location2, gDir;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    gDir = new GDirections();        
}

function showLocation() {
    geocoder.getLocations(document.form2.pickUp.value, function (response) {
        if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
        {
            alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the first address");
        }
        else
        {
            location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
            geocoder.getLocations(document.form2.dropOff.value, function (response) {
                if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
                {
                    alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the second address");
                }
                else
                {
                    location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                    gDir.load('from: ' + location1.address + ' to: ' + location2.address);
                    calculateDistance();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function calculateDistance()
{
    GEvent.addListener(gDir, "load", function() {

        var drivingDistanceKilometers = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;
        document.getElementById('dist').value = drivingDistanceKilometers;

    });
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="initialize()">

<form name="form2" onSubmit=" showLocation(); " method="post" action="bookings.jsp" >

<input type="text" id="dist" name="dist" value="0" >
<input name="pickUp" type="text">
<input name="dropOff" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
```

Inside bookings.jsp:

```
<body>
<% 
String dist = request.getParameter("dist"); 
out.println(dist);
%>
</body>
```

Comment: are you sure you have a value in `drivingDistanceKilometers`

Comment: @Tariq Yes. If i have no form action then the distance value appears in the text box when i click my submit button.

Comment: Actually working with plain JSP. There is not difference at all as compare to HTML or PHP pages. You need to look through you code. Or better share some more code to make us have better idea of the problem

Comment: @Tariq Shared more code.

Comment: Did you debug your Javascript? Can you set a breakpoint on the line `document.getElementById('dist').value = drivingDistanceKilometers;`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have a input field with name dist. What you need to do is modify you html and insert this into you form

`<input type="hidden" id="dist" name="dist" value="0"/>`

So your code may look like this:

```
<form name="form2" onSubmit=" showLocation(); " method="post" action="bookings.jsp" >

<input type="hidden" id="dist"  value="0"/>
<input name="pickUp" type="text">
<input name="dropOff" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: I tried with `<input type="hidden" id="dist" name="dist" value="0" >`
This did not work.. so i changed the type to text. Now it shows me the distance in textbox but `out.println(dist);` gives me value = 0